# Python script works fine when run regularly, but not when compiled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have a script that generates a UI which gets altered based on certain buttons. 
When I run my script standalone it works totally fine, from start to finish.

Issue is, when I compile it with PyInstaller (I **do not** use onefile or windowed), the GUI breaks while throwing this error:

```
    invalid command name "1940661235784UpdateUI"
    while executing
"1940661235784UpdateUI"
    ("after" script)
 at load function
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "UserInputs.py", line 614, in <lambda>
  File "UserInputs.py", line 921, in ShowLoadMenu
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If this code works prior to pyinstaller, what could cause this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: I dont see `tkinter` on the supported packages list for `pyinstaller`  [Supported packages](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages)

Comment: I saw the same, but it does suppor tkinter. Found the issue being that since it compiles in a new directory, a relative path I had written in my code wasn't being used. Changing that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller compiles to a dist folder with all the dependencies inside, since I use relative paths in my code, the new folder was trying to pull from what didn't exist.